# Python Flask unicode string encoding conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, unicode, encoding

I'm new to Flask and encoding. Using Python3
I have an app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

QUERY_PARAM = 'q'


@app.route('/response', methods=['GET'])
def get_query():
    query = request.args.get(QUERY_PARAM)
    user_input = dict()
    user_input['text'] = query
    return jsonify(user_input), requests.codes.ok
```

I put in /response?q=what is ab\u0026c

It is now returning: {"text":"what is ab\u0026c"}

I want it to return: {"text":"what is ab&c"}

Tried a couple of encoding in the code but none of them worked for me. 
Can someone tell me how I can achieve this and help me understand it?

Comment: can you try `user_input['text'] = str(query)`.

Answer (score 2):

You implementation seems to be working correctly, but you are passing the query param in a wrong way.

You want to send the text: `"what is ab&c"`.
This text needs to be encoded to encoded for urls.

For example you could use python for this, by running the following lines in the shell:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> payload = dict(q="what is ab&c")
>>> urlencode(payload)
'q=what+is+ab%26c'
```

With that result we know that the request would be:

```
http://localhost:5000/response?q=what+is+ab%26c
```

Which results in:

```
{
  "text": "what is ab&c"
}
```